# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (15-Puzzle)

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, puzzle

First of all, this question is about 15-Puzzle. And I'm trying to learning how to code it in Java language.

I have to study Artificial Intelligence at my College about IDA* algorithm, and found this link by Brian Borowski: http://brian-borowski.com/Software/Puzzle/ that was a pretty good link, but I've got an error when I'm trying to build it manually on my Eclipse.

Can anybody help me? I got an error that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Puzzle.setNumOfTiles(Puzzle.java:45)
    at Puzzle.<init>(Puzzle.java:25)
    at GUI.<init>(GUI.java:196)
    at Application.<init>(Application.java:19)
    at Application.main(Application.java:27)
```

I already tried to trace the error, google searching, but still i cannot find the solution.
It said that NullPointerException happen when some variable have a null value.
Can anybody help me here?

Here are the source code

**Application.java**

```
public class Application {

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * Creates an instance of the gui.
     */
    public Application() {
        ApplicationStarter appStarter = null;
        new GUI(appStarter); // Line 19
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * Creates an instance of the application.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Application(); // Line 27
    }
}
```

**Puzzle.java**

```
public Puzzle(final int numOfTiles) {
    super();
    setNumOfTiles(numOfTiles); // Line 25
    setSize(panelWidth, panelHeight);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
}

public void setNumOfTiles(final int numOfTiles) {
    this.numOfTiles = numOfTiles;
    dimension = (int)Math.sqrt(numOfTiles);
    imageArray = new Image[numOfTiles];
    final String file = "images/" + (numOfTiles - 1) + "-puzzle/shrksign_";
    imageArray[0] = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < numOfTiles; ++i) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(file);
        if (i <= 9) {
            builder.append("0");
        }
        builder.append(Integer.toString(i));
        builder.append(".gif");
        imageArray[i] = ImagePanel.getImage(builder.toString());
    }
    imageWidth  = imageArray[1].getWidth(null); // Line 45
    imageHeight = imageArray[1].getHeight(null);
    panelWidth  = imageWidth * dimension;
    panelHeight = imageHeight * dimension;
    state = new byte[numOfTiles];
    sleepMs = 500 / imageWidth;
    animationDone = true;
    resetOrder();
}
```

**GUI.java**

```
...

this.puzzle = new Puzzle(PuzzleConfiguration.getNumOfTiles());

...
```

Comment: Which is line 45 in Puzzle.java? What is null and should not be at this line? WHat happens when you run your code with a debugger?

Comment: Did you debug what happens at line 45? What is null there and why? Might `ImagePanel.getImage(...)` not find the image and return null in that case? ...

Comment: What is the value of `PuzzleConfiguration.getNumOfTiles()`? Do you cheched, that your gifs exist, and they have the right name?

Comment: @Thomas stupid me, after read your comment, I forgot to copy the image to my workspace, and it works now. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right about the meaning of the exception:

> It said that NullPointerException happen when some variable have a null value.

What you need to do is look at the `setNumOfTiles` method, specifically line 45 (of the whole source file, not of the method) and see what happens there.

Most probably you are using an uninitialized variable **OR** passing one as an argument.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `imageArray[1]` holds a null value. It may be either that ImagePanel.getImage() return `null` for the element 1, or that numOfTiles >= 1 so the loop does not run.

Your loop begins at i and preincrements, it means that there is no loop run with i = 1 (the first iteration runs with i = 2). I would use this form

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfTiles; i++) {
```

EDIT:

Thomas is right; that way, either numOfTiles is too low (1 or less) or `ImagePanel.getImage` returns null (a missing resource file?)

Comment: Actually, that's not true. There _is_ an iteration with `i = 1`. Preincrementing doesn't change the logic here as the increment operation is invoked _after_ an iteration (so in the first iteration `i` will still have the value 1).

Answer (score 0):

you have initialized the array with null values

```
imageArray = new Image[numOfTiles];
```

Then setting its values through for loop

```
imageArray[i] = ImagePanel.getImage(builder.toString());
```

but the values which are set are null and when you try to cal the method from null value you get NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION at this line

```
 imageWidth  = imageArray[1].getWidth(null);
```

imageArray[1] contains null values.  calling . on null always caz NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION